# Why does my comboBox show all but one of its values grayed out, and doesn't allow them to be selected?

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a ComboBox with the values 1..21

When I drop down the comboBox, number 1 (item 0) is enabled, but all the other items are grayed out, and I can't select any of them. In fact, I can only see their values when scrolling through the list - otherwise they are completely transparent.

Here is my winrt-xmal:

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxInitialMapZoomSetting" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="32" Margin="4" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="CmbxInitialMapZoomSetting_OnSelectionChanged">
                <Button Content="1"/>
                <Button Content="2"/>
                <Button Content="3"/>
        . . .
                <Button Content="19"/>
                <Button Content="20"/>
                <Button Content="21"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

...and here is the related code:

```
private void CmbxInitialMapZoomSetting_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MapZoomSetting"] = cmbxInitialMapZoomSetting.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: It's a 'clash' of the default styles for the combo box and the button under the "Dark" theme. Bottom line, you'll need to create a style with appropriate foreground/background colors for the button and/or the ComboBox that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are putting `Button`s in `ComboBox`? You could use `ComboBoxItem`s instead:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbxInitialMapZoomSetting" Height="32" Margin="4" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="CmbxInitialMapZoomSetting_OnSelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

You only need a minor modification of your event handler to make this work:

```
private void CmbxInitialMapZoomSetting_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MapZoomSetting"] = (cmbxInitialMapZoomSetting.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I didn't declare the items as buttons; they are declared that way automatically when you add items via the Properties pane.

Comment: Perfect - that works like the proverbial cha[mp,rm], except that at design-time the comboBox is now shown expanded/dropped down.

Comment: @ClayShannon For me its expanded at design time only when in XAML view the focus is on `ComboBox` or one of its items. Its collapsed otherwise.